# Designing ManyToMany relationships between Users in Django

Tags: django, model-view-controller, model

I'm a little rusty with django and I was hoping someone could help me with a really quick question concerning ManyToMany relationships. My app allows Users to give Comments about other Users, so I'm not sure if under the class Comment, I should have one or two ManyToManyFields(User).. like one for receiving the comment and one for giving? Or is just having one ManyToMany enough? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='comment_owner')
    peer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='comment_peer',
                         verbose_name=u'Собеседник')
    content = models.ForeignKey('CommentContent')


class CommentContent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```